# create django models from existing sqlite db

Tags: django, sqlite

I am used in creating orm and leaving django responsible for creating the tables.But in a project I am involved I have to create a simple CRUD application a frontend for an existing database. The database was created by creating the tables manually. So I have two tables Table1 and Table2 which have a many to many relationship through Tables12. Tables12 looks like the table that django would normaly create using a ManyToManyField thus it has two fields the id's of the two models. So after using django's inspectdb, django successfully created the models according to the SQLite database. The many to many tables like Tables12 was created like the following(as stated above):

```
class Tables12(models.Model):
    table1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1)
    table2 = models.ForeignKey(Table2)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "Tables12"
        unique_together = (("table1_id", "table2_id"),)
```

Trying the following gives me an error:

```
>> table2 = Table2.objects.get(pk=1)
>>tables12 = Tables12.objects.filter(table2=table2)
>>tables12
OperationalError: no such column: Tables12.id
```

I am guessing Django's orm is expecting an id field in every models created. How can I bypass this behavior? Is there a way to edit the tables so as they look more like django's orm but behave as the existing db's tables? Like:

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    #pre exsiting fields
    table2 = models.ManyToManyField(Table2)
```

or

```
class Table2(models.Model):
    #pre existing fields
    table1 = models.ManyToManyField(Table1)
```

but without destroying database records and without creating tables from start.

Comment: what is the name of your primary key on that table? I assume that your db does not use ID as the PK. Django offers the possibility for you to mark which field is the primary key with "primary_key=True". https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key. No sure however if this is what you need.

Comment: That's the problem Tables12(the many to many relationship table) didn't have a primary key when created. So naturally inspectdb didn't create one. How can I bypass it

Comment: In this case run an alter table sql, create the primary key and set it to autoincrement.

Comment: So there isn't another way to do it, as this would  mean altering the existing's database schema which I don't think is possible. Should I use flask instead and SqlAlchemy?

Comment: But this is RDBMS theory. How else would you link the tables together if they are not actually connected? How would you write an sql query to retrieve the information and join the tables?

Comment: Sorry kinda lost you there. Are you talking about the intermediate table "Tables12" the one that is representing the relationship? It has the foreignkeys table1 and table2. Or didn't I understand something?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `Tables12` model, and specify the `db_table` argument to a `ManyToManyField`:

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    tables2 = models.ManyToManyField(Table2, db_table='Tables12')
```

You would still not be able to query the `Tables12` model directly (it still exists and has an `id` field), but this would allow you to use the `JOIN`s Django generates for a `ManyToManyField`:

```
table1 = Table1.objects.get(pk=1)
tables2 = table1.tables2.all()
```

This would still not allow you to use Django to write to the join table, but it allows you to use the data that's in it. If at all possible, I'd strongly recommend adding a primary key.

Comment: Thanks. Will this work and when creating a new record? E.g
new_table1 = Table1()
new_table1.save() #new_table1.id = 54
new_table2 = Table2()
new_table2.save() #new_table2.id = 83
new_table1.tables2.add(new_table2)
The code should add to Tables12 the record (54, 83) and just that.

Comment: "This would still not allow you to use Django to write to the join table."

Comment: hmmmm. Thank you. SqlAlchemy was used for this project. And as I can see from the tutorial It can produce the intermediate table in a ManyToMany field with no primary id

Comment: A future version, most likely 1.9, will support composite primary keys. That would allow pretty much the same behaviour.

Comment: It didn't work...I added the many to many field but when I did
tables2 = table1.tables2.all() threw an error of no attribute with name tables2

Comment: It worked. But as you said add isn't working. There is now workaround instead of creating an id on the tables correct?